# I would like to add condition to Django DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views, detailview

I am using Django Generic view, DetailView.
But I'd like to block users to access to detail post who did not email_confirmed yet.
I have a email_confirmed field in User model.

My code is :

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login/'), name='dispatch')
class RecruitView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Recruit
    template_name = 'recruit.html'
```

and I want to add :

```
    if not request.user.email_confirmed:
        error_message = "you did not confirmed yet. please check your email."
        return render(request, 'info.html', {'error_message': error_message})
    else: pass
```

How can I add this condition to DetailView?

(I tried to override 'as_view' but I don't know how to do it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin). With this you can specify specific permissions users need to have or override the [`has_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin.has_permission) method.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class RecruitView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    ...

    login_url = '/login/'
    permission_denied_message = 'you did not confirmed yet. please check your email.'

    def has_permission(self):
         return self.request.user.email_confirmed
```

This will redirect users without the `email_confirmed` to the `login_url` where you can display the error message. In order to use the `index.html` template instead you might need to override the [`handle_no_permission`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.contrib.auth.mixins/PermissionRequiredMixin/#handle_no_permission) method.

Comment: Since you're not checking a permission, it might be cleaner to use [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) and override `test_func`.

Comment: Wow! It was my first question, and I am very impressive!! Thank you so much, you saved me :)